# How to send a retrieved table through PHP mail() function

Tags: php, mysql

The below code gives the output as how in screenshot. I want to send this content via php mail function . When i try to add this code into $message , It doesnt work as it contains php code(to retrieve data from table) in between html code. Kindly help on how this can be achieved ?
[image]

```
This is the code i was trying out for email . 
<?php
 include('db.php'); //connection to database
 $to = 'example@gmail.com';
 $subject = "test php mail" ;
 $message = '
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title> Fetching data </title>
   </head>
  <style>
      table, th, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
       border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th{
        color:#DC143C;
        }

     td {
        color:#0000FF;
        } 
  </style>
  <body>
  <font size="4" face="Courier New" >
   <table border="1" style="width:50%" align="center">

   <tr bgcolor="#2ECCFA">
              <th style="padding: 20px" bgcolor="#E6E6FA" 
            color="#DC143C" color="red">Word of the Day</th>
   </tr>

   <!-- I used while loop to fetch data and display rows of date on html 
   table -->

    <?php
    $records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hindiday order by 
    rand(curdate()) 
    limit 1 ");
    while ($course = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
        echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$course['hindiword'] . ' ' .$course['phonetic'] . ' ' 
       .$course['id']." </td>"; "</tr>" ;  
        }
   ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html> ' ;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: abc@gmail.com.com>' . "\r\n";
    // Send email
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)):
    $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
    else:
    $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
    endif;
   ?>
```

Comment: can you please add your mail code
also, you need to add the message in one variable of PHP
e.g
$message = ' <html>Any containt</html>';

Comment: i have added the code i was trying. Kindly help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looping outside the string, and the concatenate the result like so :

```
$string = ''; // The variable used to contain your data

$records = mysql_Something is wrong("SELECT * FROM hindiday order by rand(curdate()) limit 1 ");
while ($course = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    //Filling that variable
    $string .= "<tr>";
    $string .= "<td>".$course['hindiword'] . ' ' .$course['phonetic'] . ' ' .$course['id']." </td>"; "</tr>" ;  
}

//Using the variable in your message
$message = '
     ...
     '. $string .' 
     ...
';
```

That way wherever you want to add the $string you just concatenate it, as if you try to execute PHP code inside a string it'll be considered as a string and the PHP in question won't be executed.

So the final result would look like this :

```
<?php
 include('db.php'); //connection to database
 $to = 'example@gmail.com';
 $subject = "test php mail" ;
 $string = ''; // The variable used to contain your data

 $records = mysql_Something is wrong("SELECT * FROM hindiday order by rand(curdate()) limit 1 ");
 while ($course = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
      //Filling that variable
      $string .= "<tr>";
      $string .= "<td>".$course['hindiword'] . ' ' .$course['phonetic'] . ' ' .$course['id']." </td>"; "</tr>" ;  
    }
 $message = '
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title> Fetching data </title>
   </head>
  <style>
      table, th, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
       border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th{
        color:#DC143C;
        }

     td {
        color:#0000FF;
        } 
  </style>
  <body>
  <font size="4" face="Courier New" >
   <table border="1" style="width:50%" align="center">

   <tr bgcolor="#2ECCFA">
              <th style="padding: 20px" bgcolor="#E6E6FA" 
            color="#DC143C" color="red">Word of the Day</th>
   </tr>

   <!-- I used while loop to fetch data and display rows of date on html 
   table -->
    '. $string .' 
    </table>
    </body>
    </html> ' ;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: abc@gmail.com.com>' . "\r\n";
    // Send email
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)):
    $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
    else:
    $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
    endif;
   ?>
```

Comment: $message = '
      <font size="4" face="Courier New" >
    <table border="1" style="width:50%" align="center">

       <tr bgcolor="#2ECCFA">
                  <th style="padding: 20px" bgcolor="#E6E6FA" 
                color="#DC143C" color="red">Word of the Day</th>
       </tr>
'
$records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hindiday order by rand(curdate())limit 1 ");
while ($course = mysql_fetch_assoc($records))
{
$message .= "        <tr>";
$message .= "            <td>".$course['hindiword']."</td>";
$message .= "        </tr>";
}
$message .= "
  </table>"
It did not work

Comment: Of course it didn't work @KeerthanaA as you didn't do what I did in my answer. I'll post a full code answer.